# Bootstrap Two columns side by side one full width with image other with in container with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve this output 
[image]

I want to show this text with in red box & red box mean with in container.
right side is fine but left side having issues..

i tried this

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.p-r {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    }</style>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6">
          <h1>SCANNING & DIGITIZATION</h1>
          <p>We are engaged in all forms of document digitization, image scan & data capture. From microfilm / microfiche and aperture card scanning, to automated invoice processing, through to large format scanning and everything in between. We process well over a million per pages a month on site or in our client’s offices. We have decades of experience, a highly knowledgeable staff and scalable capacity. With clients from virtually every industry, we are used to tight turnarounds and can provide the software, hardware, and manpower to assist with backfile conversion or document digitization, freeing you to concentrate on business.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 p-r">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOGb2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-full">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Yorkford/bzhsLz06/)

```
.p-r:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 200%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOGb2.jpg) no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Yes almost this but how to show full picture inside that column its not showing complete picture.

Comment: At the moment this is the solution that i use when i have tasks like this, you can try and edit your image(in photoshop) so that it can look the best. If i have some new updates i will tell you

Comment: your answer is perfect but my concern is width: 200%; due to this my full picture not showing well.

Comment: Yes i understand, but this is like this because if it is 100% your image will be inside the column, it won't go outside of it. And like said in the other comment you can try modifying the image in photoshop